# Drupal 7: Adding a 'Add New Listing' (Create Content) Link on Local Tasks Menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I am working on making user pages for a certain type of user who can add/edit/delete content on my Drupal site. I've figured out how to use Views to create a 'Manage Listings' tab which appears on the user's profile, now I need to make another Local Task tab (or any kind of link) that allows the user to add new content.

I tried just adding a header to the view using basic markup text that contains:

```
<a href="node/add/">Add New Listing</a>
```

But because the link is displayed from the 'users/admin/' page, the link ends up bringing them to 'users/admin/node/add/' which doesn't exists (obviously). How can I create a create content link without messing up the path?

Below is a visual for help:

[image]

Please excuse the fact that this is a very simple question - this is my first attempt at building a Drupal site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use /node/add instead because then it is relative to url instead.